# How do I input boolean Truth values to a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean-expression

```
#executing the XOR gate

print('Enter a truth value for each of the variables and get A XOR B.')
print('Enter A')
a = input()
print('Enter B')
b = input()
print('The XOR gate value is:')
print(((a and (not b)) or ((not a) and b)))
```

So it's pretty obvious that I'm trying to input Boolean key words `True` and `False` into variables `a` and `b` to get the output of an XOR gate.

The issue here is that the input function is evaluating the `True` or `False` input to be a string instead of a Boolean registered word and the program is always returning `False` as the answer.

I would like to know if there is a way to input and store Boolean values in variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any non-empty string evaluates to the boolean `True`. Even `bool('False')` is `True`.

You can use `a = True if input().lower() in ('t', 'true') else False`

(or the shorter form, `a = input().lower() in ('t', 'true')`)
and same for `b`.

Of course this does not have to be in a single line, and you can decide what logic is used to decide which strings are allowed/interpreted as `True` or `False`.

**Do not** go the `eval` way.

`ast.literal_eval` *may* be used, but will accept any literal (int, list, string).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've already tried this way, I just wanted to know if there is a way to assign Boolean values like in C with the `bool` data type?

Comment: @RoshanKomaravolu `a` will be `bool`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = input()[0].lower() in '1ty'
```

This accepts `1`, `true` and `yes` (among others) in a case insensitive way as True.

Answer (score 0):

just compare the values of input with True if, its true return `a = True` else `a =False`. By default input() takes a string as input, so, we can convert it like this.

```
#executing the XOR gate

print('Enter a truth value for each of the variables and get A XOR B.')

print('Enter A')

a = True if input() == 'True' else False

print('Enter B')

b = True if input() == 'True' else False

print('The XOR gate value is:')

print(((a and (not b)) or ((not a) and b)))
```

So, just write `True` or `False` for inputs.